# Improving checkout time in ADO pipeline by using fetchTags

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Trying to improve our git checkout time by adding fetchTags=false property. However, while trying to run the pipeline, I am seeing the error "Unexpected value 'fetchTags'".
Can someone please tell me from which version onwards is the fetchTags property included? I can't seem to find that information from the release notes.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2022/pipelines/sprint-209-update?tabs=yaml.

We are on Version Azure DevOps Server 2022 (AzureDevOpsServer_20221122.1)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this Release Note: [Azure DevOps Server 2022 Update 1 RC1 Release Date: September 19, 2023](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2022u1?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#do-not-sync-tags-when-fetching-a-git-repository) -> [Do not sync tags when fetching a Git repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2022u1?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#do-not-sync-tags-when-fetching-a-git-repository)

> To opt-out from syncing the tags through YAML file, add the fetchTags: false to the checkout step. When the fetchTags option is not specified, it's the same as if fetchTags: true is used.

To use the **fetchTags** option in YAML pipeline, you need to upgrade the Azure DevOps Server 2022 to Azure DevOps Server 2022 Update 1 RC1.

You can upgrade the Azure DevOps based on the guidance on the doc above.